# Passing android.text.format.Time object via Intent from one activity to another

Tags: android

Is there any way to pass an object of `Time` class via `Intent`? I have searched for passing objects via `Intent`, but they don't solve my problem as the `Time` class does not inherit `Parcelable` class or implement the `Serializable` interface.

Comment: Is there a reason why you need an actual `Time` object? Could you just use `toMillis` and pass the `long` through?

Comment: or u can pass the time in string/int and again can get similar time obj using intent. or make it static( just a workaround)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass objects using `Singleton`. Pesonally I use this method, since parsing objects is too complex to achieve such a simple goal.

```
public class Session {

    public static final Session sharedSession = new Session();

    public Time passedTime;

    private Session() {

    }
}
```

Then you access to this `passedTime` in any `Activity` or `Fragment` like this:

```
Time time = Session.sharedSession.passedTime;
```